# EXCEL IF statement Issue

Tags: excel

I am facing issues with the `IF` statement, I have a sheet that needs to be updated daily given new daily inputs.

In a daily basis, I will be using the formula "`=today()`" to get the update for my desired inputs, let's say production for product X, in the end of the day the summation of the production will be presented in "`Daily Production Cell`", this is working smoothly.

This cell will change daily based on the the previous day production.

I would like to have a record for the entire month, so beginning for example 1 September to 30 September.

I have added the dates from 1 to 30 September in column A, A1 representing Sep 1 and so on. In the desired output cell, I used Given a scenario where we want the production for 1 of Sep and today is the 1st of sep. I have used an if statment:

`=If(A1=today(),1,0)` - If it is 1st of Sep paste 1 if it is not paste 0 - Let's call this (Date Cell) (Cell B1 to B30)
so we weill have 30 Cells of these, 1 for each day.

Considering our situation, The pasted value would be 1 for today

Further,another cell which is the output cell starting in column C would be:

C1 Cell: `=if(B1=1,(Daily Production Cell), C1)`

If the B1 is 1 paste the daily production cell here, if not "KEEP" the existing number here.

It runs smoothly.

Going into the second of september, it will run smoothly as well and the output value of the second of september will be displayed,

In this scenario, cell B1 will be zero and cell B2 will be 1, because of the date.

However, when referencing the cell C1 - The value displayed is ZERO, while C2 will have the correct figure. Whenever I move to the corresponding day the output value for the desired day will display correctly, BUT the previous days output cell (C1,...) will be zeros, so the values are not reserved!

For example if we reach to 10 Sep, we will have the correct number for C10 which is the sum production for this day, but C1,C2,C3....C9 will get zeros, I need the previous numbers to reserve and not change.

Appreciate your support!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You posted a very long text, I think it would be simpler to "show, not tell".  Preferably not as pictures. Make some trivial examples of what you have and what you want. You can use [this table generator](http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), remember to enclose in code tags. See [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this, for the date of 26 Sep:

```
          A        B    C    
 --- ------------ --- ------ 
  1   01-09-2022   1   3386  
  2   24-09-2022   1   5988  
  3   25-09-2022   1   5153  
  4   26-09-2022   1   5314  
  5   27-09-2022   0   BLAH
```

you can make an additional condition on formula in column B:

`=IF(OR($A1=TODAY();TODAY()>$A1);1;0)`

This will *KEEP* the value for any date that has passed.

Likewise you will have to "protect" column C, so that you don't update to same value every day. For row 1: `=IF(AND($B1=1;TODAY()=$A1); (daily production cell); C1)`

Your job could have been done easily using a macro or external automation.

If this is not what you want, please clarify your question.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, I have ran the formulas and it works smoothly for the same day, even the previous days are displayed with their corresponding productions, However, when I refrence the production for the previous day into another cell, it still gives me zero. From the cell where it is the same day which is today, when I refrence it it will give me the value. Please let me know if you need more clarification.